# The navigation prop is missing for this navigator react navigation 3.x

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

> I am new to react native and I am using React navigation 3.x.  This is
>   my project structure.

```
 Mydemo
  ----routes
      --Home.route.js
  ----src
      --pages
        --AddUser.js
  ----App.js
```

> Below I am sharing my route configurations:-
>
> Home.route.js code:-

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import AddUser from '../src/pages/AddUser';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
        Add:{
            screen: AddUser
        }
    })

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

App.js Code:-

```
import {createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import HomeStack from './routes/Home.route';

export default createSwitchNavigator({
  Home: HomeStack
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});
```

**But I am getting this error:-**

> The navigation prop is missing for this navigator.

can anyone please guide me about what I am doing wrong ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createAppContainer` must be on top of your navigation config =>

**Home.route.js**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import AddUser from '../src/pages/AddUser';

export default createStackNavigator({
    Add: AddUser
})
```

**App.js**

```
import {createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import HomeStack from './routes/Home.route';

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Home: HomeStack
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```